# Find smooth global maximum from noisy points

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameter-tuning

Let's say I have a number of sampled data points and resulting values for each.  In practice this may be a high dimensional problem, but here's a one dimensional example:

[image]

In the above example, the point at 35 is the maximum value, however, the points a little higher drop off significantly, so a smooth maximum that accounts for noise might be closer to 25.

Is there a standard model or algorithm that could be used to accomplish this automatically?  This example is a cross-validation score for different values of the `n_estimators` hyperparameter of the `RandomForestRegressor` class in `sklearn`, but in practice I would need to optimize multiple hyperparameters.  Is there something that could accomplish finding the global maximum but for higher dimensions, i.e., more hyperparameters in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to understand what you meant, given that you also have a near-maximum at 50. But I think you mean you want to lower the risk, and stay away from that nasty looking minima at around 45?

Averaging each point with its neighbour on either side gives you that. Averaging with N points either side makes it smoother, the higher N is. Even better is a weighted average, so points further away have less influence.

(It looks like `N` is another hyperparameter we need to tune for! But I think  we can guess say N should be 1 or 2 when dealing with a small number of points like this.)

I didn't find a moving average function in scikit, but in pandas there is `pandas.Series.rolling()`. Or the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/q/14313510/841830 could be useful.

Additional: My first thought had been to run this smoothing on each dimension (e.g. each hyperparameter), one at a time. But you can expand the idea to more dimensions: it would require using a nearest-neighbours algorithm to decide which are the N neighbours to average with. It might be more efficient to instead calculate the distance to every other neighbour, and weight based on inverse-distance or inverse-distance-squared. (So all other points influence the result, but the nearer ones have more influence.) It'll require playing around with the relative weight for the original point.

Comment: Not sure I'm following exactly.  The points aren't evenly sampled along the x axis, so you might be smoothing some points that have an x delta of 1 (e.g., the points at around x=40 in the plot) and maybe others that have an x delta of >5 (e.g., x<25 above).  In the absence of more information, you'd want the influence of each point on the others to be a consistent function of distance.

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah Yes, good point: weight by distance in x-axis could make it more useful. Depends on how complex you are willing to get: moving average code is generally made for analyzing time series, where we assume they are evenly sampled (and missing values already been interpolated). So you are more likely to need to roll your own.

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah I also updated my answer, as I'd overlooked you were asking about higher dimensions - where it seems to tie in naturally with weighting by distance.